# How to count elements with two "restrictions"?

Tags: xquery

My XML looks something like this :

```
<books>
    <book id="b1">
      <title>Set theory and the continuum problem</title>
      <category>Mathematics</category>
      <location>
        <area>hall1</area>
        <case>1</case>
        <shelf>2</shelf>
      </location>
      <description>A lucid, elegant, and complete survey of set theory.</description>
      <history>
        <borrowed by="m4"/>
        <borrowed by="m2" until="2018-04-05"/>
      </history>
    </book>
    <book id="b2">
      <title>Computational Complexity</title>
      <isbn>978-0201-530-827</isbn>
      <category>Computer Science</category>
      <location>
        <area>hall1</area>
        <case>3</case>
        <shelf>3</shelf>
      </location>
      <description>.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="b3">
      <title>To mock a mockingbird</title>
      <isbn>1-292-09761-2</isbn>
      <category>Logic</category>
      <category>Mathematics</category>
      <location>
        <area>hall1</area>
        <case>1</case>
        <shelf>3</shelf>
      </location>
      <description>.</description>
     </book>
</books>
```

Is it possible to count how many books are there with elements area='hall1' and case='1'?

I tried this:

```
count(//books/book[location/area='hall1'])
```

but i do not know how to include case='1' "restriction" also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
count(//books/book[location/area='hall1'][location/case='1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

** ADDITIONAL QUESTION **

Is it possible to list all book's titles which have area='hall1' and case='1'?

```
for $bb in //books/book[location/area='hall1'][location/case='1']
    let $n := //books/book/title
return <book>$n</book>
```